# Associate TypeScript language with its tag

Tags: support, feature-request, tags, code-formatting

Code blocks on questions tagged with [TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) should be automatically formatted with TypeScript syntax highlighting. Currently, they are not (at least not always), despite the presence of TypeScript support in the formatting engine (`<!-- language: lang-typescript -->`) does work).

When added [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25139422/145173), I had to add the comment to get the formatting to work; however, when I added [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25139228/145173), I did not.

Comment: On your second answer it's using JavaScript syntax highlighting, because the question is tagged as such.

Comment: @Stijn I thought it had to be TypeScript because `class`, `static`, `private`, and `IHttpService` were all highlighted. Maybe not, though: upon checking, I see the first 3 are [keywords or reserved in ECMAScript 6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar). I don't know why `IHttpService` got picked up, but if there's a reason for that, then maybe the formatter doesn't support TypeScript after all.