# Can the Angular tag automatically imply the language as javascript?

Tags: feature-request, tags, code-formatting

Similar to this question [Associate TypeScript language with its tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267768/associate-typescript-language-with-its-tag) we could do with the same functionality with [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular).

Currently I find myself editing Angular questions (which often don't have [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) associated) repeatedly  to include the language prefix (`<!-- language: lang-js -->`). If you want an example just check any question in this tag, hardly any of them will have correct syntax highlighting (Here's an [actual example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55629171/cannot-read-property-user-data-of-undefined-ngrx)).

Comment: There is no `lang-ts` highlighting. [tag:typescript] uses `lang-js`.

Comment: You sure about that @Stijn. Because [it seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55628142/revisions)?

Comment: That's a default fallback. Try `<!-- language: lang-nonexistinglanguage -->` and you'll see the same result.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I must of copied that of something somewhere. Anyway, updated question

Comment: I find a lot of questions tagged `typescript` asking questions which have multiple duplicates in `javascript` because people think there's a big difference (witness https://stackoverflow.com/q/55630975/215552). Adding the `javascript` tag to a lot of the `angular` tagged questions would not necessarily be a bad idea...

Comment: Don't disagree @HereticMonkey . It's just a barge though, people rarely tag the language in Angualr questions, JS or TS

Comment: I don't disagree, but then I see you switching to having to frequently add the angular tag to questions that are tagged with one of the version tags only ;)